# adding markers to Google maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to add markers to a google map, from predfined variables `addrstartname` and `addrEndName`. It worked grand in v2 however simply doesn't display in v3.

```
function addMarker2Map(point,markerID,imageUrl) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker(point, {
    draggable: false,
    autoPan: false,
    title: (markerID.toLowerCase().indexOf("start") != -1) ? 'Start Point: ' + addrStartName: 'End Point: ' + addrEndName
  });
    marker.id = markerID;
    marker.setMap(map);
    marker.setIcon(imageUrl);
  if (markerID.indexOf("tart") != -1) {
    dirMarkerFrom = marker;
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(point) {
      findAddrLocations(point, geocoderGetLocsFrom, geocoderNotFound);
    });
   } else {
   dirMarkerTo = marker;
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(point) {findAddrLocations(point, geocoderGetLocsTo, geocoderNotFound);});
   }
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (point) {
   if (this.id.toLowerCase().indexOf("start") != -1) {
       this.openInfoWindow("<div style='width:200px'><img src='images/google_pointer_start.png' alt='Start Address' title='Start Address' align='middle' /> <strong>Start Address:</strong><br />" + addrStartName + "</div>");
       } else {
      this.openInfoWindow("<div style='width:200px'><img src='images/google_pointer_finish.png' alt='End Address' title='End Address' align='middle'/><strong>End Address:</strong><br />" + addrEndName + "</div>");
   }
 });
}
```

I was getting errors around the `marker.setIcon(imageUrl);` yesterday however it is working fine today.

An example of calling this function also can be seen here

```
   google.maps.event.removeListener(mapClick); 
    if (point != undefined){
   addMarker2Map(point,markerID,imageUrl)
                   }
```

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor for the [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) is incorrect.

It only takes one parameter, a [MarkerOptions object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions)

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker(point,{draggable:false, autoPan:false, title:       (markerID.toLowerCase().indexOf("start") != -1)?'Start Point: '+addrStartName:'End Point:     '+addrEndName});
```

should be:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point, draggable:false, autoPan:false, title:       (markerID.toLowerCase().indexOf("start") != -1)?'Start Point: '+addrStartName:'End Point:     '+addrEndName});
```

Comment: Thank you, ive implemented that but no luck im afraid. Ive added an example of when i call this function to the code in my original post.

Comment: Then there are more issues (luck shouldn't be involved).  You need to provide enough code for us to replicate the problem (or a jsfiddle that exhibits the issue or a link that does)